# Where can I find a GUI for creating vhosts?

Tags: user-interface, vhosts

Creating Vhosts is very formulaic, so I was wondering if there were any GUIs that simplified the process.

I've read about Webmin, so it seems like that may work.  Do any IDEs help with this, or built in admin control panels for Mac or Windows?

Answer (score 3):

On OS X, I know of at least 2 options for creating Apache2 vhost entries through a GUI:

[VirtualHostX](http://clickontyler.com/virtualhostx/) and [MAMP Pro](http://www.mamp.info/en/mamp-pro/index.html)

Both are paid apps, and the main difference is that MAMP Pro works with it's own, self-contained Apache2/MySQL/PHP environment and doesn't touch OS X's native AMP configuration. VirtualHostX, on the other hand, can work with OS X's built-in Apache2 or with other server configurations, like MAMP (the self-contained AMP stack used by MAMP Pro, but free and without the GUI) or XAMPP.

I have no idea what the solutions are for other OSes.

Answer (score 0):

On Windows you can try [HOSTSignalz](http://hostsignalz.com). It is very similar to VirtualHostX. It works with XAMPP or WAMP or even just a Native Apache installation.